# invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int (*)(std::vector<deptrum::DeviceInformation>&)’

Tags: c++, linux

when I run this code, it goes wrong.

```
void* triangle = dlopen("../lib/libdeptrum_tof.so", RTLD_LAZY);
std::vector<deptrum::DeviceInformation> device_list;
int (*GetDeviceList) (std::vector<deptrum::DeviceInformation>& device_list);
GetDeviceList = dlsym(triangle,"GetDeviceList");
```

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Apparently this crappy API expects you to cast a `void*` to a function pointer, so you need an explicit cast. (And that would also be UB in C++ and C both.) Is there an alternative to this lib? Because it smells old *nix skunky design.

Comment: @Lundin there is some .h file, But they are all function declaration that don't include code details

Comment: You *have to* cast the `void*` to a function pointer. Luckily, `dlopen` and `dlsym` are only available on POSIX systems, where such a cast is required to work (despite being undefined by the C++ standard).

Comment: Now if only Linux was open source... then someone could replace ancient POSIX skunkware with well-written libraries. Instead of keep re-using the skunkware lib for another 30+ years...

Comment: Linux is a subset of Posix, so inventing a Linux-only solution wouldn't do much good. (Also using a typecast should be trivial, so the problem isn't really a problem. See also malloc/realloc: they return `void *` which has to be type-casted in C++))

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `auto f = reinterpret_cast<YourFunctionType*>(dlsym(…));`.